# How to use grails.plugin.location?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a plugin project which I created as `grails create-plugin myPlugin`. I also created a 'normal' grails project as `grails create-app myPluginDemo`. I'm trying to install `myPlugin` plugin in `myPluginDemo` but don't understand how to use `grails.plugin.location`.

Where do I put `grails.plugin.location` inside `BuildConfig.groovy`? Inside `plugins` section? Inside `repositories` section?

What should I append to `grails.plugin.location`? Should it be `grails.plugin.location.myPlugin`? Or `grails.plugin.location.grails-my-plugin`? Something else?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`grails.plugin.location` is not a dependency resolution, so it goes outside `grails.project.dependency.resolution`.

It should be like below, if both `myPluginDemo` and `myPlugin` are in the same directory. Moreover, this will not install the plugin into the app, but the application will refer to the file system for the plugin which is convenient in development mode. In order to use the packaged plugin it has to be referred in `plugins` inside `grails.project.dependency.resolution`

```
grails.plugin.location.myPlugin = "../myPlugin"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    repositories {

    }
    dependencies {

    }
    plugins {

    }
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly does it mean for the plugin to be "not installed"? If I do this with my project, the plugin does appear among those installed in the `grails install-plugin` list. The app tries to compile the source files from the plugin if I do `grails compile` or `grails run-app`. So in what way is the plugin "not installed"? Will it not be packaged if I run `grails war`?

Comment: I am thinking that this is a use-case for using a CI system like Jenkins, am I right?

Comment: @ThomasFarvour Nope, this practice is good during development. CI system like Jenkins should depend on the plugin as a dependency in the app and should not refer to a physical location in the CI build server.

Comment: Ah.  Thank you.  I understand this now.  I think we've been Doing It Wrong then. :(