# installing a local dojo plugin on grails 2.2.3

Tags: grails, plugins, dojo

I'm trying to install a dojo plugin plugin from a local directory, but I get a grails error:

> plugin not found.

The problem is that I try to do something kind new for using the dojo 1.9 librery. I am using Ubuntu 10.04, 64 bit architecture, and the Spring IDE GGSTS. I am trying to install default dojo plugin (1.7) on grails from the internet that downloads the plugin to a local directory. The thing lay on the modification of the related plugin, uncompressed  it, change the dojo library on `web-app/js/dojo` directory for the update one dojo 1.9. files. Then uninstall dojo plugin, remove the dojo cache on `.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.pluggin/` and on the `.grails/GRAILS_VERSION/project/_PROJECT`. After these, only rest the modified plugin installation by install-plugin command. The problem is that grails return an error:

```
plugin () not found

Loading Grails 2.2.3
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Warning The install-plugin command is deprecated and may be removed from a future version of Grails.  Plugin dependencies should be expressed in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.  See http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#pluginDependencies.
| Resolving plugin /home/israel/dojo-1.7.2.0.zip. Please wait...
| Error resolving plugin [name:/home/israel/dojo-1.7.2.0.zip, group:org.grails.plugins, version:latest.integration]. Plugin not found.
| Error Plugin not found for name [/home/israel/dojo-1.7.2.0.zip] and version [not specified]
| Error Error installing plugin: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
| Error     at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

With current Grails version 2.2.3 you are using, `install-plugin` has been deprecated. You need to define it in your buildConfig. If you have the plugin in maven repository just define it in plugins dsl otherwise you need to define it inline using `grails.plugin.location` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115635/how-to-use-grails-plugin-location). Take a look at [creating and installing plugins](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#12.1%20Creating%20and%20Installing%20Plug-ins).

Comment: hi. thanks or the replay but the fact that is deprecated it does not explain why can't not install. if i install dojo using the install-plugin command it complete the installation informing the same warning message preventing that the installation in that way is deprecated. In my case i want install a local plugin.

Comment: Take a look at the link I sent you for inline plugins.