# Grails Plugins from GitHub

Tags: grails

If I want to use a plugin for Grails from Git Hub. Do I just download the zip file and make it available in my local maven repository? I'm behind a firewall which doesn't let me just resolve the dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't build from the repo source since that might include unfinished features and bugs. At the very least use source tagged for a particular release (if there are any).

If you want to download *released* plugins, they're available at http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/

Keep in mind that running `grails install-plugin /path/to/zip` no longer works in 2.3, so you should stay away from that approach. Instead, you could run a local Artifactory instance that acts as a cached plugin repo - see this thread for some information to get started: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Caching-plugins-using-artifactory-td4640164.html

Answer (score 4):

You can get the source and run `maven-install` to make it available in your local maven repository, then you declare the dependency in the plugins block of the `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Answer (score 1):

The zip file which will be downloaded will be the source of the plugin. You have to extract the zip, go to the root of the plugin, and run `grails maven-install` (from release plugin) which would build the plugin artifact for you in you local maven repository if you have one setup.

Then you can use the plugin.

OR

You can use the plugin inline as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116125/2051952).

Answer (score 1):

Proxy setting can also be configured in grails by add proxy and set proxy.

> grails add-proxy myproxy "--host=myproxy" "--port=myport" "--username=proxyuser" "--password=mypassword" 
>   grails set-proxy myproxy 
>   [see grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html).

if above solution doesn't work try then
create ProxySettings.groovy in C:\Documents and Settings\user-name.grails folder

add following two lines to this file and save

```
myproxy=["http.proxyHost":"myproxy", "http.proxyPort":"4300", "http.proxyUserName":"proxyuser", "http.proxyPassword":"mypassword"] 
currentProxy="myproxy"
```

[please check this link for more options](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Solution-to-Grails-Proxy-Issue-for-installing-plugins-on-windows-td2994191.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep plugins locally as described here

http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2011/10/project-setup-for-grails-with-customized-plugins-using-git-submodules/

```
git submodule add git://github.com/sarmbruster/grails-spring-security-ui.git plugins/grails-spring-security-ui
git add .gitmodules plugins/
git commit -m "added submodule"
```

now add plugins/grails-spring-security-ui as a inline plugin by adding to grails-`app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.location.'spring-security-ui'="plugins/grails-spring-security-ui"
```

That's all.

More info in section "Installing Local Plugins" and "Specifying Plugin Locations" in docs:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#12.1%20Creating%20and%20Installing%20Plug-ins