# Get reference to domain id in grails audit-logging plugin

Tags: grails, audit-logging

I'm trying to use grails `audit-logging` plugin. It seems to do what I need to do.

But, I'm having problem referencing `id` for a domain class where `id` is automatically generated.

```
class Person {
 static auditable = true

 String name
 String email


 def onSave = { newState ->
     println "new person inserted"

     // I want to get id of newly inserted person 
     // When I do newState[id], I get null

     // newState[name] works as expected
 }

}
```

When I try to reference `id` as for other attributes, I get `null`.

How can I get reference to `id` so that I can get `id` of newly inserted `Person` entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently a [**Pull Request**](https://github.com/robertoschwald/grails-audit-logging-plugin/pull/6) was merged to do exactly what is being looked for.

A snapshot build (1.0.1-SNAPSHOT) will be available soon following which there will be a release build (1.0.1) asap. In the mean time you can clone the plugin and use it inline.

As part of the above PR `id` is made available for `onSave` event hook, but right now it is already available for logging and to enable id logging to `AuditEventLog` table there is a config setting provided by the plugin as:

```
//Config.groovy
auditLog {
    logIds = true // to log ids of objects in audit table
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any workaround I can do? Or else, can you please instruct me some guidance to use cloned repo in my project?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16116125/2051952) is how you can use an inline plugin. If the plugin is cloned to a location same as your app (for example) then you can use as `grails.plugin.location.'audit-logging' = "../grails-audit-logging-plugin/grails-audit-logging-plugin"` (note the repo is a wrapper over the plugin and a test application)

Comment: [Latest version of plugin v1.0.1](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging) is released today with the above PR. You can use it now. Hope that helps. @TheKojuEffect