# How to disable resources of a grails plugin

Tags: javascript, css, grails, plugins, resources

I am working on a project which I have divided into several independent plugins. So like wise for each functionality I have a plugin which is integrated and can be re-used in another project.

So now I am using the plugin of my theme in development mode without packaging with `grails.plugin.location.'MyThemePlugin' = "../MyThemePlugin"`

All goes well till now but these is another plugin which I recently integrated and it has few same CSS and JS file names but of very old versions. So due to this problem my theme breaks and does not work.

So is there any way to disable the resource (css and js) files of this other plugin?

Comment: What is the grails version and do you have used resource plugin or asset-pipeline plugin?

Comment: @Ramsharan My grails version is 2.4.4 and I have not changed the default plugins so yes there is `asset-pipeline:1.9.9`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no use of the css and js file of the new plugin then why don't you simply delete those files from plugin directory itself. Inline plugin editing seems should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes that can be the temporary solution but the problem is that if I do what you said and I push the code on git and when my code will be pulled then those files will be downloaded on their computers with the plugin and again the problem will come.

Comment: You can resolve dependency using location [inline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115635/how-to-use-grails-plugin-location).
But the correct way would be to use your own maven repo for the modified plugin.